# how to format time output in python

Tags: python

Below is my sum program in Python.

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

sum = 0
for num in range(0,10000001):
sum = sum + num
print(sum)
print("--- %s seconds ---" %.2f (time.time() - start_time))
```

Output:

```
50000005000000
--- 6.02535605430603 seconds ---
```

The question is how to get the output up to 2 decimal points.

Comment: Instead of `%s` you need to use `%.2f`. Apparently you tried to do that but got confused. Simply change the last line to `print("--- %.2f seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))`

Answer (score 1):

just stick with Python 3.x formatting and along with that, you have more predefined functions to make your life easier, you have [more formatting options](https://pyformat.info/) though.

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

sum = 0
for num in range(0,10000001):
    sum = sum + num
print(sum)
print("--- {} seconds ---".format(round(time.time() - start_time,2)))
```

Comment: thank you for answering my question and providing the link.